# Where can I find U-boot's makefile line that creates symbolic links?

Tags: makefile, u-boot

I am using U-boot on a arm64 system. I found it rather odd that U-boot does not have a folder for this architecture ( there is no folder aarch64 in arch ). This would not allow me to compile it using the command:

```
    make CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- ARCH=aarch64
```

instead I have to use :

```
    make CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-
```

However, I was stubborn and decided to force this a bit and copied the arch/arm folder onto arch/aarch64

However ( sigh, as expected ) I have some issues now under the form that U-boot creates some symbolic links to folders. Example : proc -> proc-arm and arch -> arch-armv8
However these links are placed in the arm folder, not in the aarch64 folder.

I have tried to modify the mkconfig file, but it still doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently U-boot is a bit of a trickster. After specifically enforcing the board configuration :

```
if [ "${ARCH}" -a "${ARCH}" != "${arch}" ]; then
    echo "Failed: \$ARCH=${ARCH}, should be '${arch}' for ${BOARD_NAME}" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
```

It goes on to forcefully switch to arm:

```
# Test above needed aarch64, now we need arm
#
if [ "${arch}" = "aarch64" ]; then
       arch="arm"
fi
```

I think I also understand why they chose to do this. A quick review of my commit revealed a lot of duplicate code, which would be much harder to track.